# Dimensions For Matrix Multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

Can anyone explain why the following code produces *input_t* with a shape of (32,) instead of (,32), given the fact that *inputs* has a shape (100, 32)? Shouldn't input_t produce a vector with 32 attributes/columns?

```
import numpy as np

timesteps = 100
input_features = 32
output_features = 64

inputs = np.random.random((timesteps, input_features))

state_t = np.zeros((output_features,))

W = np.random.random((output_features, input_features))
U = np.random.random((output_features, output_features))
b = np.random.random((output_features,))

successive_outputs = [ ]

for input_t in inputs:
    output_t = np.tanh(np.dot(W, input_t) + np.dot(U, state_t) + b)
    successive_outputs.append(output_t)
    state_t = output_t
```

Comment: What is `U` parameters for? Is this supposed to be a neural network?

Comment: Yes, it's a simple naive implementation of RNN found [here](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine the matrix `inputs` as a 2D table. You have 100 rows and 32 columns. Then the for loop acts as an iterator which will return values along the first dimensional axis. This dimension thus disappears and returns the remaining dimensions. When there is a single dimension the default in Python is $(n,)$.

A matrix $(100, 32)$ iterates through $(32,)$

A matrix $(100,28,28)$ iterated through $(28,28)$

A matrix $(100,2,2,2)$ iterated through $(2,2,2)$

Comment: Re: "When there is a single dimension the default in Python is (n,)." - Does this mean Python will **transpose** the columns to rows by default, in this example?

Comment: Yeah it can be seen as a transpose. But it's just the way the data is passed as a one dimensional array.

Comment: It makes sense. For insight, I was ultimately evaluating how the matrices `W` and `input_t` posses the correct dimensions for multiplication in `np.dot(W, input_t)`. Thanks for the insight!